# C code retaining chars from prior setting

Tags: c

I've got a bit of C code that is running in an Objective-C application. I snagged this code off the internet.

```
static void extract_app_name(const char *all_arguments, char **app_name) {
    char *full_path, *app_end, *app_begin; //, *app_name_temp;
    size_t diff;

    if (all_arguments == NULL || app_name == NULL) {
        return;
    }

    full_path = (char*)all_arguments + sizeof(int);

    app_end = strcasestr(full_path, ".app");
    if (app_end == NULL) {
        app_begin = strrchr(full_path, '/');
        if (app_begin != NULL) {                
            *app_name = malloc(app_begin+1);
            *app_name = strdup(app_begin+1);
        } else {                
            *app_name = strdup(full_path);
        }
    } else {            
        app_begin = app_end;
        while (*(--app_begin) != '/') {}
        diff = app_end - app_begin; 
        char *app_name_temp[diff]; // = malloc(diff);
        *app_name_temp = malloc(diff);
        *app_name = malloc(diff);
        strncpy(*app_name_temp, app_begin+1, diff-1);
        app_name_temp[diff]='\0';
        app_name = strcpy(*app_name, *app_name_temp);
    }
}
```

The intent of this code is to extract the application name from a full path. If the application is named with a `.app` extension, it pulls the name from whatever proceeds the .app.

For example, the following:

```
extract_app_name("/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/Versions/16.0.912.63/Google Chrome Helper.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome Helper", &app_name);
NSLog(@"First App is: %s", app_name);

extract_app_name("/System/Library/Frameworks/QuickLook.framework/Resources/quicklookd.app/Contents/MacOS/quicklookd", &app_name);
NSLog(@"Next App is: %s", app_name);

extract_app_name("/System/Library/CoreServices/Dock.app/Contents/XPCServices/com.apple.dock.extra.xpc/Contents/MacOS/com.apple.dock.extra", &app_name);
NSLog(@"Next App is: %s", app_name);

extract_app_name("/Applications/Tiny", &app_name);
NSLog(@"Next App is: %s", app_name);
```

Should output this:

```
First App is: Google Chrome
Next App is: quicklookd
Next App is: Dock
Next app is: Tiny
```

Generally, that's correct. But if I run the app 4-5 times back to back, my output will sometimes not always work out. Sometimes the second app which should output `quicklookd`, will actually dump `quicklookdome` (it retains part of the first app's name).

I suspect it has to do with the variable not being initialized properly and retaining what's already at that spot in memory. I just don't know C well enough to pin-point it.

Comment: Mind that everytime you call the function you should call `free(app_name)` to avoid a memory leak. This is because the function is using `malloc` to get some memory to put the string into.

Comment: The line `*app_name = malloc(app_begin+1);` also doesn't make sense for a couple of reasons; you're passing a pointer as the size to `malloc` and also immediately after assigning a value to `*app_name` you're assigning it the value returned by `strdup`.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is, fixed and simplified:

```
    static void extract_app_name(const char *all_arguments, char **app_name) {
        char *full_path, *app_end, *app_begin; //, *app_name_temp;
        size_t diff;

        if (all_arguments == NULL || app_name == NULL) {
            return;
        }

        full_path = (char*)all_arguments + sizeof(int);

        app_end = strcasestr(full_path, ".app");
        if (app_end == NULL) {
            app_begin = strrchr(full_path, '/');
            if (app_begin != NULL)
                *app_name = strdup(app_begin+1);
            else
                *app_name = strdup(full_path);
        } else {
            app_begin = app_end;
            while (*(--app_begin) != '/') {}
            diff = app_end - app_begin;
            *app_name = malloc(diff);         
            strncpy(*app_name, app_begin+1, diff-1);
        }
    }
```

Note that your code has a memory leak. The caller to `extract_app_name` should free the string when it's done with it.

Comment: I am still experiencing the same behavior with these changes in place.